# how to revert changes to Ubuntu configuration file without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, configuration, sudo

I modified `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and now I get the following error:

> sudo: unknown uid XXXXX: who are you?

Which means I can't use `sudo` to change the file back.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can we see what did you edited or we should guess?

Comment: I changed the first three entries passwd, group and shadow. Before they were files XXX XXX and now they are files ldap